Chain Rule in $n$-dimension in Proof of 1st-order MVT in $\mathbb{R^n}$
1st-order MVT in $\mathbb{R}^n$: 
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \in C^1$, then for $x,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, 
$f(x+v) = f(x) + \nabla f(x+\theta v)\cdot v$, for $\theta \in (0,1)$.
Proof: 
$g(t) := f(x+tv)$ 
$g'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} f(x+tv) = \sum_{i=1}^n [\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}(x+tv)\cdot \frac{d(x+tv)_i}{dt}]$ 
... (apply 1st-order MVT in 1-dimension to $g(0+1)$ to complete the proof)
I am clueless to how the proof arrived at the equality in the second line of the proof.
First, in the first part of the sum, why are we taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_i$? Why not with respect to $v_i$? Why are we evaluating the p.d. at point $(x+tv)$?
Second, I thought that by the Chain Rule, the second part of the sum,$\frac{d(x+tv)_i}{dt}$, implies that $x_i = (x+sv)_i$, but it looks very wrong.

We have $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R},\,\mathbf{x}\mapsto f(\mathbf{x})$ and define
$$g(t):=f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v})$$
for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. That is, if we define $h(t)=\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v}$, we can write $g(t)=f(h(t)).$ The chain rule than says that
$$ g'(t)=\nabla f(h(t))\cdot h'(t)=\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{v} $$
where $\cdot$ is the scalar product in $\mathbb{R^n}$. In the end,
$$
g'(t)=\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{v} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v})\,\mathbf{v}_i
$$

If I understand correctly, the reason why the we're performing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is because the function $f$ takes variable $x$ as an input, and we don't take the partial derivative with respect to $v$ is because we treat $v$, the change in $x$, as a constant?

Yes, that is indeed correct.
